# ContentVersion records created in test not returned by query in execution

Tags: apex, unit-test, contentdocument

I'm trying to test an apex class where I send an email. In said email, I add attachments where I have to use queries to find the contentversions and creating attachments based on those, for instance:

```
for(ContentVersion plano : [SELECT Title, VersionData, FileType FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId IN :contentDocumentIds AND IsLatest = true AND Title LIKE 'Atelier Plano%']){
    attachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
    attachment.setFileName(plano.Title);
    attachment.setBody(plano.VersionData);
    attachment.setContentType(contentTypes.get(plano.FileType));
    attachments.add(attachment);
}
```

I'm trying to create those records in my test class so I can cover that code (I have several blocks like that one in my method so if I don't cover it, I would never reach 75%)

This is how I'm creating the data, first I create a contentVersion record:

```
ContentVersion contentVersion = new ContentVersion(Title = 'Atelier Plano', PathOnClient = 'Pic.jpg', VersionData = Blob.valueOf('Test Content'));
```

Then, I query for the ContentDocument that gets created alongside the contentVersion:

```
List<ContentDocument> documents = [SELECT Id, Title, LatestPublishedVersionId FROM ContentDocument];
```

(Its a list because I'm creating more than one ContentVersion)

Then I create the ContentDocumentLink using the contentdocumentId:

```
    ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink();
    cdl.LinkedEntityId = apt.Id;
    cdl.ContentDocumentId = documents[0].Id;
    cdl.ShareType = 'V';
    cdl.Visibility = 'AllUsers';
```

Doing this, for some reason my method can't find the contentversions I'm generating in my test class. I'm thinking maybe for some reason, they don't have IsLatest = true, but why? Aren't they the only version so by logic the latest? Any help would be appreciated...

EDIT: If I query the contentversion records in my test class, the rows are returned. Why don't they in my tested apex class?
The Apex method I'm testing is using the InvocableMethod annotation. Could that be affecting the state of the records or something in execution?

Comment: what we're not seeing is how you are invoking the code-under-test

Comment: @cropredy I don't know what you mean by code-under-test.

Comment: @cropredy the method I'm testing is using the InvocableMethod annotation. Do you think that may be affecting to the state of the records somehow?

Comment: invocable method is not the issue - where are the testmethod lines that show the calling of the invocable method?